# Error:- The method selectByVisibeText (String) is undefined for the type WebElement

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to SELENIUM, i am getting the error in last line. Can you guys please tell me the solution and the reason of this issue.
ERROR:- "The method selectByVisibeText(String) is undefined for the type WebElement"

```
package kemgo_package;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.apache.bcel.generic.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class kengo_class 
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","E:\\geckodriver-v0.19.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    System.out.println("Hello");
    WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://kemgov2.cladev.com");   
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println("hello world-----2");
    driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/header/div[2]/nav/div/ul[2]/li[3]/a")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("userClearBtn")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/section/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/a/span[1]")). selectByVisibeText("Test_Product01");    // Error:-  "The method selectByVisibeText(String) is undefined for the type WebElement"



}
}
```

Comment: selectByVisibeText(String) works only for the Select class for the conventional select tag. https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/. YOu have a dropdown created by li and ul tags.

Comment: Trying to figure out. But still not getting the exact solution.

Comment: You can use the by.XPath search and use the text() property in the xpath. `.//*[text()='Username']`

Comment: It will not login using the credentials in your code, so I can't get past that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your error:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/section/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/a/span[1]")). selectByVisibeText("Test_Product01");    // Error:-  "The method selectBy**Visibe**Text(String) is undefined for the type WebElement"
```

It's spelled "Visible", with a lower-case "L" between the "b" and the "e".

Comment: Great catch (+1)

Comment: Not to worry: If I had a nickle for all the workdays I've wasted on mistakes like that, I'd not be a programmer anymore :-)